# My HTC ONE M8 bluetooth cant connect with other phones

Tags: bluetooth, connection-issues, htc

My htc m8 doesn't connect with other phones with android higher than 5.1 but with bluetooth speaker or a device with android 4.4 work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flash the official firmware or another rom